# Checkbox that triggers a Textbox in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a checkbox that triggers a textbox via ng-hide. After saving, the checkbox cannot trigger the textbox anymore. As i have investigated on, the state of the textbox is stuck to its state before the save was clicked. When i force the page to reload using location.reload(), the textbox works perfectly again. The problem is that i should have a modal that says "Your data is saved" and if i use location.reload(), the modal will not pop up. Is there a way to reset the state of the textbox without reloading? If not, is there a way where i can force a modal to show after location.reload()?

Comment: What does the save method involve? Also you could post some code along with the question.

Comment: Hello @DrinkBird, the save method includes running through scope.content using for loop to get all the data within the form and returns $http.post(url, params) to return to the page and a showModal after. I will prepare the codes and edit it later, sorry for not posting.

Comment: No problem. It seems to me that you are approaching forms a bit wrong. The standard way is to define `ng-model` directives to your form inputs, and these will fill out an object in your scope. Check out this very good guide http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change ng-hide by ng-show and use ng-checked and trigger the textbox via the checkbox using the angularjs binding like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="myvar == true;">
<input type ="text" ng-show="myvar">
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer but the problem is with the state after saving. My save includes $http.post. Any idea?

Comment: You need to be more clear adding some code example, however I wanna ask you, Does the server response it's working well?